# Ping Result:General Failure When disconnect from vpn

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn

In Windows 8 When i connecte to the vpn and then disconnect from it, i get general failure.

```
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

the routing table are:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0                   0.0.0.0    192.168.137.1   192.168.137.86     30
```

But it won't work, but when i add two other routing route it will work successfully:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
128.0.0.0                 128.0.0.0    192.168.137.1   192.168.137.86     30
0.0.0.0                   128.0.0.0    192.168.137.1   192.168.137.86     30
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Both of networks(Vpn and default network gateway) have Internet Connection

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this seems to be a known issue for Windows 8, see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itpronetworking/thread/760542b6-5701-4aa4-97d7-c1dd45a3c913/).

Can you try to see if this happens on any other OS too? If this problem doesn't occur for them then it's probably the bug in Windows 8.

I've got this same problem myself on my own Windows 8 system so I don't think it has been fixed yet.

Comment: I see this problem on many windows 8 laptops :(