# Windows 8: Ping Result : General Failure after disconnect from vpn

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, routing

In Windows 8 When i connecte to the vpn and then disconnect from it, i get general failure.

PING: transmit failed. General failure.
the routing table are:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0                   0.0.0.0    192.168.1.1   192.168.1.86     30
```

But it won't work, but when i add two other routing route it will work successfully:

I need to disable and enable the interface to continue working with internet.

I saw this problem, on many windows 8 clients.

I ask such question last year, but it have no workable answer.
[Ping Result:General Failure When disconnect from vpn](https://superuser.com/questions/556240/ping-resultgeneral-failure-when-disconnect-from-vpn/571570#571570)

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping Result:General Failure When disconnect from vpn](http://superuser.com/questions/556240/ping-resultgeneral-failure-when-disconnect-from-vpn)